# Lifetime parameter for `Self` in trait signature

Tags: rust

Consider this simple protocol implementation:

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Debug)]
enum Req<'a> {
    InputData(&'a [u8]),
    Stop,
}

impl<'a> Req<'a> {
    fn decode(packet: &'a [u8]) -> Result<Req<'a>, String> {
        match packet.first() {
            Some(&0x01) => Ok(Req::InputData(&packet[1..])),
            Some(&0x02) => Ok(Req::Stop),
            _ => Err(format!("invalid request: {:?}", packet)),
        }
    }
}

#[derive(PartialEq, Debug)]
enum Rep<'a> {
    OutputData(&'a [u8]),
    StopAck,
}

impl<'a> Rep<'a> {
    fn decode(packet: &'a [u8]) -> Result<Rep<'a>, String> {
        match packet.first() {
            Some(&0x01) => Ok(Rep::OutputData(&packet[1..])),
            Some(&0x02) => Ok(Rep::StopAck),
            _ => Err(format!("invalid reply: {:?}", packet)),
        }
    }
}

fn assert_req(packet: Vec<u8>, sample: Req) {
    assert_eq!(Req::decode(&packet), Ok(sample));
}

fn assert_rep(packet: Vec<u8>, sample: Rep) {
    assert_eq!(Rep::decode(&packet), Ok(sample));
}

fn main() {
    assert_req(vec![1, 2, 3], Req::InputData(&[2, 3]));
    assert_req(vec![2], Req::Stop);
    assert_rep(vec![1, 2, 3], Rep::OutputData(&[2, 3]));
    assert_rep(vec![2], Rep::StopAck);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2f18b3f0bd485a1360495055aa4d4980&version=stable)

This works, but the two functions `assert_req` and `assert_rep` have identical code with only a difference in types. It is a good idea to write one generic `assert_packet`:

```
trait Decode<'a>: Sized {
    fn decode(packet: &'a [u8]) -> Result<Self, String>;
}

#[derive(PartialEq, Debug)]
enum Req<'a> {
    InputData(&'a [u8]),
    Stop,
}

impl<'a> Decode<'a> for Req<'a> {
    fn decode(packet: &'a [u8]) -> Result<Req<'a>, String> {
        match packet.first() {
            Some(&0x01) => Ok(Req::InputData(&packet[1..])),
            Some(&0x02) => Ok(Req::Stop),
            _ => Err(format!("invalid request: {:?}", packet)),
        }
    }
}

#[derive(PartialEq, Debug)]
enum Rep<'a> {
    OutputData(&'a [u8]),
    StopAck,
}

impl<'a> Decode<'a> for Rep<'a> {
    fn decode(packet: &'a [u8]) -> Result<Rep<'a>, String> {
        match packet.first() {
            Some(&0x01) => Ok(Rep::OutputData(&packet[1..])),
            Some(&0x02) => Ok(Rep::StopAck),
            _ => Err(format!("invalid reply: {:?}", packet)),
        }
    }
}

fn assert_packet<'a, T>(packet: Vec<u8>, sample: T)
where
    T: Decode<'a> + PartialEq + std::fmt::Debug,
{
    assert_eq!(T::decode(&packet), Ok(sample));
}

fn main() {
    assert_packet(vec![1, 2, 3], Req::InputData(&[2, 3]));
    assert_packet(vec![2], Req::Stop);
    assert_packet(vec![1, 2, 3], Rep::OutputData(&[2, 3]));
    assert_packet(vec![2], Rep::StopAck);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=7cd9c7ef80b9cd4e54cf73011a0bd78b&version=stable)

However, this triggers a "does not live long enough" error:

```
error[E0597]: `packet` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:41:27
   |
41 |     assert_eq!(T::decode(&packet), Ok(sample));
   |                           ^^^^^^ does not live long enough
42 | }
   | - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the function body at 37:1...
  --> src/main.rs:37:1
   |
37 | / fn assert_packet<'a, T>(packet: Vec<u8>, sample: T)
38 | | where
39 | |     T: Decode<'a> + PartialEq + std::fmt::Debug,
40 | | {
41 | |     assert_eq!(T::decode(&packet), Ok(sample));
42 | | }
   | |_^
```

If I understand correctly, the problem is in the function signature:

```
fn assert_packet<'a, T>(packet: Vec<u8>, sample: T)
where
    T: Decode<'a>
```

Here, `packet` is destroyed when the function returns, but the user-provided `'a` lifetime parameter says that the lifetime should end somewhere outside the `assert_packet` function. Is there any right solution? How should the signature look? Maybe [higher rank trait bounds](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/nomicon/hrtb.html) could help here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why does this compile:

```
fn assert_req(packet: Vec<u8>, sample: Req) {
    assert_eq!(Req::decode(&packet), Ok(sample));
}
```

while this doesn't?

```
fn assert_packet<'a, T>(packet: Vec<u8>, sample: T) where T: Decode<'a> + PartialEq + std::fmt::Debug {
    assert_eq!(T::decode(&packet), Ok(sample));
}
```

The difference is that in the first version, the two textual occurrences of `Req` name two different instances of the `Req<'a>` struct, with two different lifetimes. The first occurrence, on the `sample` parameter, is specialized with a lifetime parameter received by the `assert_req` function. The second occurrence, used to invoke `decode`, is specialized with the lifetime of the `packet` parameter itself (which ceases to exist as soon as the function returns). This means that the two arguments to `assert_eq!` don't have the same type; yet, it compiles because `Req<'a>` can be coerced to a `Req<'b>` where `'b` is a shorter lifetime than `'a` (`Req<'a>` is a subtype of `Req<'b>`).

On the other hand, in the second version, both occurrences of `T` must represent the exact same type. Lifetime parameters are always assumed to represent lifetimes that are longer than the function call, so it's an error to invoke `T::decode` with a lifetime that is shorter.

Here's a shorter function that exhibits the same problem:

```
fn decode_packet<'a, T>(packet: Vec<u8>) where T: Decode<'a> {
    T::decode(&packet);
}
```

This function fails to compile:

```
<anon>:38:16: 38:22 error: `packet` does not live long enough
<anon>:38     T::decode(&packet);
                         ^~~~~~
```

It's possible to use higher rank trait bounds on this function to make it compile:

```
fn decode_packet<T>(packet: Vec<u8>) where for<'a> T: Decode<'a> {
    T::decode(&packet);
}
```

However, now we have another problem: we can't invoke this function! If we try to invoke it like this:

```
fn main() {
    decode_packet(vec![1, 2, 3]);
}
```

We get this error:

```
<anon>:55:5: 55:18 error: unable to infer enough type information about `_`; type annotations or generic parameter binding required [E0282]
<anon>:55     decode_packet(vec![1, 2, 3]);
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

That's because we didn't specify which implementation of `Decode` we want to use, and there are no parameters the compiler can use to infer this information.

What if we specify an implementation?

```
fn main() {
    decode_packet::<Req>(vec![1, 2, 3]);
}
```

We get this error:

```
<anon>:55:5: 55:25 error: the trait `for<'a> Decode<'a>` is not implemented for the type `Req<'_>` [E0277]
<anon>:55     decode_packet::<Req>(vec![1, 2, 3]);
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

That doesn't work, because the `Req` we wrote is actually interpreted as `Req<'_>`, where `'_` is a lifetime inferred by the compiler. This doesn't implement `Decode` for *all* possible lifetimes, only for one particular lifetime.

In order to be able to implement your desired function, Rust would have to support [higher kinded types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kind_%28type_theory%29). It would then be possible to define a type constructor parameter (instead of a type parameter) on the function. For instance, you'd be able to pass `Req` or `Rep` as a type constructor requiring a lifetime parameter to produce a specific `Req<'a>` type.

Answer (score 0):

It works correctly if you link the lifetimes involved to the input which you'll be referencing, e.g.

`fn assert_packet<'a, T>(packet: &'a [u8], sample: T) where T: Decode<'a> ..`

(You'll also need to update the tests to pass borrows rather than owned `Vec`s.)

Comment: You are right, but then I'm forced to create `packet` outside the `assert_packet` function. After all, it works somehow with owned buffer in non-generic version `assert_req`/`assert_rep`, so (I hope) it should be possible to implement the same thing with trait.