# how to annotate trait implemetation which returns Self, has specified lifetime?

Tags: rust

title seems to be similar with [Lifetime parameter for `Self` in trait signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33481868/lifetime-parameter-for-self-in-trait-signature) but I create this new post because I believe root cause is different.

I have a trait like following

```rust
trait T<'a> {
    fn new(y: &'a Y) -> Self where Self: Sized;
    fn do_something(&self);
}
```

and want to write generic function that accept type X (which implements trait T<'a>), and reference of Y, then create dyn Trait T<'a>.

```
fn create_t_from_i<'a, I: T<'a>>(y: &'a Y) -> Box<dyn T<'a>>
```

my naive implementation is like this

```
fn create_t_from_i<'a, I: T<'a>>(y: &'a Y) -> Box<dyn T<'a>> {
    return Box::new(I::new(y)) as Box<dyn T<'a>>;
}
```

then I got this error.

```
error[E0310]: the parameter type `I` may not live long enough
```

but parameter type `I` has constraint `T<'a>`, I don't figure out why this does not tell `rustc` to `I::new(y)` is alive after execution step go out from this function.

I suspect this is happened by `I:new()` returns `Self`, which has no lifetime annotation. but also I cannot find the way to give lifetime annotation to Self.

this is full example to cause the error.

```
struct Y {
    z: i32
}

struct X<'a> {
    y: &'a Y
}

trait T<'a> {
    fn new(y: &'a Y) -> Self where Self: Sized;
    fn do_something(&self);
}

impl<'a> T<'a> for X<'a> {
    fn new(y: &'a Y) -> X<'a> {
        return X::<'a> {
            y: y
        }
    }
    fn do_something(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.y.z)
    }
}

fn create_t_from_i<'a, I: T<'a>>(y: &'a Y) -> Box<dyn T<'a>> {
    // error: the parameter type `I` may not live long enough
    return Box::new(I::new(y)) as Box<dyn T<'a>>;
}

fn main() {
    let y = Y { z: 123 };
    {
        let t = create_t_from_i::<X>(&y);
        t.do_something()
    }
}
```

if I remove definition of T::new and giving X::new to create_t_from_i as function pointer, code seems work (need to use T + 'a instead of T<'a>). but what essential difference is from 1st example?

```
struct Y {
    z: i32
}

struct X<'a> {
    y: &'a Y
}

trait T {
    fn do_something(&self);
}

impl<'a> X<'a> {
    fn new(y: &'a Y) -> X<'a> {
        return X::<'a> {
            y: y
        }
    }
}
impl<'a> T for X<'a> {
    fn do_something(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.y.z)
    }
}

fn create_t_from_i<'a, I: T + 'a>(ctor: fn (y: &'a Y) -> I, y: &'a Y) -> Box<dyn T + 'a> {
    // if passing constructor function directly and using annotation I: T + 'a, rustc does not complain. 
    let i = ctor(y);
    return Box::new(i) as Box<dyn T + 'a>;
}

fn main() {
    let y = Y { z: 123 };
    {
        let t = create_t_from_i::<X>(X::new, &y);
        t.do_something()
    }
}
```

anyone have an idea why this happens and how to make `rustc' happy?

regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```rust
fn create_t_from_i<'a, I: T<'a>>(y: &'a Y) -> Box<dyn T<'a>>
```

is implicitly the same as

```rust
fn create_t_from_i<'a, I: T<'a>>(y: &'a Y) -> Box<dyn 'static + T<'a>>
```

which in turns means that `I` must also have a static lifetime to be able to store it in the returned box (i.e. you need a `I: 'static` bound).

To solve this, you can add another lifetime parameter for the lifetime of `I`, and use that in the returned boxed trait. This will work no matter what the lifetime of `I` actually is:

```rust
fn create_t_from_i<'a, 'b, I: 'b + T<'a>>(y: &'a Y) -> Box<dyn 'b + T<'a>> 
//                     ^^^^^^^^^                               ^^^^
```

[Playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8514bc87f91eff70738dfee09d77e3c4)

Answer (score 0):

Any trait object has a lifetime annotations, which will implicitly be `'static`.
Your function is thus:

```
fn create_t_from_i<'a, I: T<'a>>(y: &'a Y) -> Box<dyn 'static + T<'a>>
```

The solution is to explicitly annotate your trait object's lifetime:

```
fn create_t_from_i<'a, I: 'a + T<'a>>(y: &'a Y) -> Box<dyn 'a + T<'a>>
```